# What are the recommended strategies for authorising API calls from my react native application to my node server?

Tags: node.js, authentication, react-native, authorization

I have a react native application that I want to make API calls from. I am getting confused about how I should be authorising these calls on the node back end.

Method 1:

User logs in to application and authenticates, I then return a JWT with refresh token. This is then stored client side / in react native app and is sent upon each request. If token expires, then refresh using refresh token.

Method 2:

Create API key for each client. When a user creates an account, I create an API key (or maybe access key and secret key like AWS does) and send that with each request.

Is there a preferred / recommend method out of these two? Perhaps they are not mutually exclusive? Do I still need to provide an API key to my react native app so that it can make API calls and then I use JWT for authenticating users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal opinion,

You may go for the **Method 1**, since it is not secure to store / create `API keys` or `Secret keys` on the client side.
JWT are more secure, you may read the following [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token#header)

In the **Method 2**, *you will most probably try this approach*

Generate Api key based on `client IP` or the `device token`, whatever suits you, and set an expiration time including the `AES` techniques, then decrypt it on the server, check the `client's IP` against the `requestor IP` and also the `expiration time`.

**Complexity and time taken** to do **Method 2** is much more that **Method 1**, *also considering I might have not covered all the security use cases*.

> Do I still need to provide an API key to my react native app so that it can make API calls and then I use JWT for authenticating users

You can make the `http` calls normally. The recommended way is call your `token generation api` and then *authenticate other valuable api's based on that* `token` *if you're using `JWT`*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds like both are plausible solutions but method 2 is a bit over kills for my requirements. JWT it is. Thanks Pritish